# Description list: Each pair on its own line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a description list and I need to locate each description in the same line with its term.

I can use the code as shown below, but I don't like it. Looks like something not professional and from the Stone Age. I believe it should be used flexbox here, but how?

```css
dt, dd { float: left; }
dt { clear: both; font-weight: bold; }
dd { margin-inline-start: 1em; } /* I would rather avoid overwriting browser defaults... */
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: *Looks like something not professional and from the Stone Age* --> and what you consider something *professional* ? flexbox is not the automatic solution for everything

Comment: HTML was there in Stone Age? :D

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry if my little friendly provocation sounded rude. What I mean is that isn't it better to use Flexbox for such a case? I rarely work work CSS, but as I know, Flexbox was created for such kind of tasks, isn't it? Also, what I really dislike is the necessity to overwrite browser defaults.

Comment: first of all, you will need to overwrite the defaults style even if you will be using flexbox then flexbox wasn't created to solve *all* the issues. It's one feature among many to be used like float so we use the one that work the best. You have a perfect working solution, so why you think you need another one using flexbox? why overcomplicating a simple task? unless you have an issue with the actual solution, I don't see why changing it.

Comment: Applying `display: flex` on `dl` helps you achieve flexbox. However, to make it more professional you may consider adding `color`, `padding` and various text formatting styles. https://jsfiddle.net/91xfqvst/

Comment: @ismi Looks good, thanks a lot. I believe with some tune-up I could make it even better to suit my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `display: flex` on `dl` helps you achieve CSS flexbox. However, to make it more professional you may consider adding `color`, `padding` and various text formatting styles.

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*change width, font-family and margin as per your requirement*/
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif
}

dt,
dd {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

dt {
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

dd {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score -1):

So basicallly i would apply `display: flex;` to `dt` as it's wrapper of child elements and apply styles like this:

```
dl {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
dt, dd {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Basically we tell flexbox to dispaly items in row and if item can't be contained in width of dl we wrapp it next line.

On `dt, dd` we just set them to be width of 50% of whole wrapper width to max out only 2 elements in line

If you need more background to it you can check out css-tricks they mad very nice guide to flex

Answer (score -1):

You will probably have to restructure the code for using flex. Here is everything what you need -> [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

For your statement

> Looks like something not professional and from the Stone Age

I would prefer using other font styling than dt, dl. These are pretty outdated